Firebase database real time push notification with new message interface
I have this error  often discussed on this site : "An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions"
My code is based on the legacy API :
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: « aa",
                body: « aa",
                sound: "default"
            }
        };
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
            .then(...)
            .catch(...);

as explained in some topics on this error saying to enabled the legacy messaging API , I tried but this legacy is no more proposed today.
So, I would to use the new API and I found this example of push notification  :
const message = {
data: {
score: '850',
time: '2:45'
},
token: registrationToken
};
getMessaging().send(message)
.then( .....)
.catch(...);
but I have now this error : "ReferenceError: getMessaging is not defined"
is someone have an example of notification with this new API or explain why I have this error?
than you
